# CocoaPods lint failing

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I'm having some issues with running pod spec lint on a small static library that I'm building. The library in question is https://github.com/seanoshea/ios-etsy-sdk and the output from the linter is available at https://gist.github.com/seanoshea/5630836.

The errors include:

```
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  ios-etsy-sdk/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyApiClient.m:19:9: fatal error: 'AFHTTPClient.h' file not found
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  ios-etsy-sdk/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyShopResult.h:22:32: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'SOSEtsyResult', superclass of 'SOSEtsyShopResult'
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  ios-etsy-sdk/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyShopResult.h:22:12: warning: class 'SOSEtsyShopResult' defined without specifying a base class [-Wobjc-root-class]
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  ios-etsy-sdk/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyShopResult.h:22:29: note: add a super class to fix this problem
```

The Podfile for the library is available at https://github.com/seanoshea/ios-etsy-sdk/blob/master/Podfile and lists AFNetworking as a dependency. When I look at the /tmp/CocoaPods/Lint directory on my machine, I notice that AFNetworking has not been downloaded which means that the .h file is not available.

Am I missing something in my podspec to ensure that AFNetworking is downloaded?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Podspec](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html) to say that it depends on AFNetworking. [Here is an example](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/AFQuickLookView/0.3/AFQuickLookView.podspec).

Comment: That was it orta. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: PS - I opened a different CocoaPods question related to a similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702814/cocoapods-linter-cannot-find-interface-declaration. If you have any thoughts on that, I'd appreciated your help.