# CocoaPods Linter: Cannot Find Interface Declaration

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoapods

I'm having an issue with CocoaPods and it finding interface files in my project. The root of the problem is:

```
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  ios-etsy-sdk/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyShopResult.h:22:32: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'SOSEtsyResult', superclass of 'SOSEtsyShopResult'
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  ios-etsy-sdk/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyShopResult.h:22:12: warning: class 'SOSEtsyShopResult' defined without specifying a base class [-Wobjc-root-class]
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  ios-etsy-sdk/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyShopResult.h:22:29: note: add a super class to fix this problem
```

The full output from running the CocoaPods linter is available at https://gist.github.com/seanoshea/5631517. When I look at the /tmp/CocoaPods/Lint directory on my machine, SOSEtsyResult is available.

https://github.com/seanoshea/ios-etsy-sdk/blob/master/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyShopResult.h is the .h file in question and it inherits from https://github.com/seanoshea/ios-etsy-sdk/blob/master/ios-etsy-sdk/SOSEtsyResult.h, so I'm not sure why the compilation fails when I run the linter.

Any ideas on this?

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you're expecting cocoapods to pull in the PCH file and to turn that into the PCH file for all of the libraries. Which it does not do ( ideally we don't want to [pollute user pchs](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#prefix_header_contents) )

Nothing says a real answer like a [pull request](https://github.com/seanoshea/ios-etsy-sdk/pull/1) though.